# Reference for denseness of testfunctions in sobolevspace

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

for my thesis I need a reference for a proof that $C_0^\infty(\mathbb R)$ is dense in $W^{2,2}(\mathbb R)$ in respect to the Sobolev-$\| \cdot \|_{W^{2,2}}$-Norm.

I have tried Google but I can't find a proper source to cite from. Do you know some book?

Thanks

Comment: Surely this is going to depend on your definition of $W^{2,2}$? Is it a completion of a space of test functions with respect to the norm, or something else?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I am used to the following definition: $W^{2,2}(\Omega) = \left\{ u \in L^2(\Omega) : \text{ the weak derivatives } u^\prime \text{ and } u^{\prime \prime} \text{ exist and are in } L^2(\Omega) \right\}$

Comment: And $\| u \|_{W^{2,2}} = \left( \|u\|_{L^2}^2 + \|u^\prime\|_{L^2}^2 + \|u^{\prime \prime}\|_{L^2}^2\right)^{\frac12}$.

Answer (score 1):

There are two theorems you need to cite.

The theorem 1 states that $W^{2,2}(\mathbb R)=W^{2,2}_0(\mathbb R)$, which can be find in page 217, remark 13 in this [book](https://books.google.com/books/about/Functional_Analysis_Sobolev_Spaces_and_P.html?id=1bFCAAAAQBAJ&hl=en)
Theorem 2 states that $C_0^\infty(I)$ is dense in $W_0^{2,2}(I)$ for any interval $I$, of course for $I=\mathbb R$. You can find this theorem in p211 theorem 8.7 for the version of $W^{1,2}$ in the same book, and read the sentence before section 8.3 on page 217 will finish the argument.

Answer (score 0):

As requested, a reference: Theorem 2.4.1 of lecture notes [*Sobolev Spaces and Applications*](http://home.iitk.ac.in/~tmk/courses/mth656/main.pdf)
by T. Muthukumar.